# Low speed because of left join

Tags: t-sql

Some times I know the performance problem of a query is because of left join , what can I do ? (replacing a sub query is suggested? )

Imagine we have tables A and B and low speed is because of the left join , what's yours recommended solution ?
Any kind of help is appreciated

```
CREATE TABLE A ( a1 VARCHAR(10),
                 a2 INT,
                 a3 INT )

CREATE TABLE B ( b1  VARCHAR(10),
                 b2  INT,
                 ab3 INT )

INSERT INTO A
VALUES ( 'a1', 11, 91 ),
       ( 'a2', 12, 92 ),
       ( 'a3', 13, 93 ),
       ( 'a4', 14, 94 )

INSERT INTO B
VALUES ( 'b1', 21, 91 ),
       ( 'b2', 22, 92 ),
       ( 'b3', 23, 93 )

-------------------------
SELECT *
FROM      A
LEFT JOIN B ON a3 = ab3
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes set up on those tables/columns?

Comment: As I check indexes don't effective in this case

Comment: I would hope you would have a primary key column in each table so you have a clustered index for those columns. And then have you tried addining nonclustered indexes on A(a3) and B(ab3)

Comment: @Stephan I believe that clustered indexes improve speed performance more than nonclustered.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon my experience i will suggest you to consider following things 
- Remove unnecessary left joins 
- Remove where clause if it can be used along with Inner join condition 
- May create indexes on your columns 
- Select desired columns, avoid using * for all columns 
- Avoid giving large lengths for your columns

Comment: Small correction: "Remove `WHERE` clause if it can be used along with an **INNER JOIN** condition"

Comment: Yes Inner Join 
Thank you